# How to use '$MATCH' as an alias of '$&'

Tags: ruby, pseudo-globals

According to [this document](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Variables_and_Constants#Pre-defined_Variables), `$MATCH` is an alias of `$&`, and I want to use it for readability.

But it doesn't work in my environment.

```
'1234-4567'.match(/\d{4}-/){ $& } # => "1234-"
'1234-4567'.match(/\d{4}-/){ $MATCH } # => nil
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I'd avoid the global variable and use `match(...) { |m| m[0] }` instead.

Comment: @Stefan: Or just `'1234-4567'[/\d{4}-/]`

Comment: @EricDuminil of course, I assumed that this is a shortened example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Human names for those [pseudo-]global variables are not enabled by default. You have to require `english` to use them.

```
'1234-4567'.match(/\d{4}-/){ $& } # => "1234-"
'1234-4567'.match(/\d{4}-/){ $MATCH } # => nil # !> global variable `$MATCH' not initialized

require 'english'
'1234-4567'.match(/\d{4}-/){ $MATCH } # => "1234-"
```